# How to use len() on dictionary list to multiple by 10 in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there away to multiples my dictionary by 10 by using len() and loops.

I need

```
my_dict={"Plants":[20, 30, 20], "Flowers":[46, 70, 57], "Trees":[14, 52, 10]
```

to become

```
my_dict={"Plants":[200, 300, 200], "Flowers":[460, 700, 570], "Trees":[140, 520, 100]
```

I Know I can get it this way but I would like to use len() if possible

```
ten = 10
for value in my_dict:
        my_dict[value][0] *=ten
        my_dict[value][1] *=ten
        my_dict[value][2] *=ten
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write another loop over the values in the lists, and if you wanted to do it by index you'd use `len`. [orlp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565635/orlp)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446506/1405065) shows what that looks like. But there are a few better ways, that don't use `len` directly.

The first option is to use `enumerate` to get indexes into the lists while you iterate over the values:

```
for lst in my_dict.values():
    for index, value in enumerate(lst):
        lst[index] = value * 10
```

Another option is to recreate the lists entirely using a list comprehension. This won't involve any indexes at all, though you do need the *keys* to the dictionary, not just the list values:

```
for key, lst in my_dict.items():
    my_dict[key] = [value*10 for value in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is a nested loop:

```
for li in my_dict.values():
   for i in range(len(li)):
     li[i] *= 10
```